# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 56

Tags: python, statistics, jupyter-notebook

I got the following 56 columns, filled with random numbers:

[image: dataframe]

What I want, is to add an extra column with the autocorrelation of column 1-56 with a certain lag. So if the lag is 1, then the outcome is 0.42, when lag is 2, 0.06 and so on.

This is the code I use:

```
def autocorr(x, t):
return np.corrcoef(np.array([x[0:len(x)-t], x[t:len(x)]]))
```

where, I presume, x is the dataframe and t is the lag.

However, when I try to add a column with the autocorrelation with lag = 1, I get:

```
df["output"] = autocorr(df,1)
```

error: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with 
    dimension 56

What am I doing wrong, or is there an easier way to calculate the autocorrelation with a defined lag?

Appreciate the help

Steven

update: I'm constantly trying to adjust, but I can't find it. Anybody?????

I tried the following code:

```
def autocorr(x, t):
return np.corrcoef(np.array([x[:len(x)-t], x[t:len(x)]]))
```

But this gives me the error:

File "", line 1
    autocorr(df(axis=1,1))
                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you mismatched the parentheses in your function call. If anything `autocorr(df(axis=1, 1))` should be `autocorr(df(axis=1), 1)`, but `pd.DataFrame` objects are not callable.

Does the `pd.Series.autocorr(lag=1)` function not achieve what you want?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
series = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, high=200, size=56))
print(series.autocorr(lag=1))
```

results in values similar to what you expected.

Update: Concerning your original problem:
Since you have one row `len(x)` is 1 and `x[0:len(x)-1]` is an empty array!
Plus: in this case `np.corrcoef` returns a 2x2 matrix of the form `[[1, C], [C, 1]]`. Your `autocorr` function works when called this way

```
df1 = df.copy(deep=True) 
df1["output"] = autocorr(df.T[0], 1)[0, 1]
```

I would not append the result to the `df` as this would change the outcome of subsequent calculations.

Comment: ps: if I would like to make 20 'output' columns with each containing the lag of 1, 2...20. What is the most efficient way to do it?